Update Pihole via SSH using Applescript and the terminal
I would like to update my Pihole using an applescript via terminal and SSH. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the syntax of Applescript and generally have few programming languages in my portfolio.
The script should do the following:
Open terminal Connect via SSH "ssh pi@192.xxx.xxx.xxx" Enter the password "xxxxxx" Obtain admin rights "sudo -i"  Update Raspberry pi "apt update "" apt upgrade -y && apt autoremove -y" --> wait until the pihole is finished and the terminal is ready for a new input Update Pihole "pihole updatePihole" exit/close the terminal
Can you help me set up such a script?
I would be very grateful!
Best regards
I first wanted to write a script that copies the individual command lines into the clipboard and copies the next command line by keystroke.
set the clipboard to "ssh pi@192.XXX.XXX.XXX"
I would then only have to insert these manually.
Unfortunately, I cannot find the "Wait" command for applescript.

This is a horrible idea! Figure out how to setup a [tag:cron] job on your Pi, and just use the pihole -up script.

Also look into UnattendedUpgrades.
